# Eclipse: "Unfortunately, XXX has stopped" error when testing on an Android phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar

Please forgive me, since this is my first time to make an Android program.

So I've followed a tutorial on YouTube to make a simple program which will take a user inputted number, multiply it by 5 and then display it on a label.

It got no errors. But when I tried to run it on my Android phone, it got the error "Unfortunately, xxx has stopped". I've checked and I could run the Hello World program that Eclipse initiated the program with.

Thank you very much for your kind attention.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.converter;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*; // * is wild character, which will import all widgets
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        Button calc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);
                    TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
                    double number = Double.parseDouble(num.getText().toString());
                    number = number * 5;
                    display.setText(number + "");
                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.converter.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_calc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.converter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.converter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
03-24 22:34:24.665: E/Trace(18634): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-24 22:34:24.845: W/dalvikvm(18634): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413b3390)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.converter/com.example.converter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at com.example.converter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
03-24 22:34:24.865: E/AndroidRuntime(18634):     ... 11 more
03-24 22:34:26.517: D/Process(18634): killProcess, pid=18634
03-24 22:34:26.527: D/Process(18634): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
03-24 22:34:26.527: D/Process(18634): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
03-24 22:34:26.527: D/Process(18634): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:951)
03-24 22:34:26.527: D/Process(18634): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:108)
03-24 22:34:26.527: D/Process(18634): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
03-24 22:34:26.527: D/Process(18634): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
03-24 22:34:26.527: D/Process(18634): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException @ MainActivity.java:28`, what's that line?

Comment: Is the XML layout your `MainActivity` layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As eltabo's answer indicates: calc is null, because R.id.btnCalculate has been declared in fragment_main.xml, but you're trying to find it in your MainActivity that loads its layout from activity_main.xml.

So the solution is to move this to your fragment like so:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Button calc = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
    final EditText num = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.num);
    final TextView display = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display);
    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double number = Double.parseDouble(num.getText().toString());
            number = number * 5;
            display.setText(number + "");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: But now I got another error. There's a "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type activity" error on these lines:

    EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);
    TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);

Comment: You need to move these out of the onClick listener, I have amended the answer accordingly

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Now variables "num" and "display" got underlined, which has the same error as before.

Comment: No worries, I think you need to check the answer again I've changed them to view.findViewById() rather than just findViewById() which tries to find the view in the activity rather than the fragment

Comment: OK edited again added final to the view declarations, this should work now

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I appreciate your patience for a dumb Java newbie. Please forgive my English as well.

Comment: No problem, please accept this answer as the correct one so that others can see this as the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
Button calc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
```

`calc` is `null`, because `R.id.btnCalculate` has been declared in `fragment_main.xml`, but you're trying to find it in your MainActivity that loads its layout from `activity_main.xml`.

Hope this helps.